# Which direction to take in regards to private home cloud storage?

Tags: server, 22.04, cloud, 22.10

I feel like I'm at a standstill in regards to my knowledge of linux and being able to create a simple home storage cloud. I have gone back and forth with document after document explaining how to create a server, use ssh to access it remotely, adding storage space, and all of the little in's and out's concerning the matter.
I'm not getting anywhere however and it's an overload of information that I obviously cannot implement correctly.
My question is one that has most likely be asked many times before, but considering the state I'm in with this software, I don't just want to give up.

What are some of the most effective strategies to get myself back on track to actually learning these systems instead of potentially destroying my setup before I even get to use it?

I apologize for the generalization, however, that's the best way I can ask for help without trying to backstep into a far too clogged memory of command line input and failed attempts.

Comment: I am a little confused about what you actually are asking. Could you elaborate a little more? Thank you!

Comment: google cloud, amazon gce, MS Azure. All 3 instant setup with ssh with backups. Takes about 2h and you are up and running. also possible with apache for a personal website (you could use as a direcory listing server for downloads) and mysq. Maintaing an actual server inhouse is more difficult and more time consuming. :)

Comment: Maximillian, I'm more leaning on the side of asking for references to sort of guide me back into the saddle when it comes to learning the vast amount of information regarding linux. Any possible guides, cookbooks, ways you have helped yourself retain information. things of that nature.
Rinzwind, thank you! I'll be sure to check those out and try and save on the stress lol.

Comment: You have reached analysis paralysis. Stop reading and start doing. Spin up a virtual machine and start building what you want. If your primary goal is to _have_ that solution rather than _build it_, then better go with @Rinzwind 's advice. Take a look at NextCloud: open source software, well documented, with every thinkable installation option: from source, on Apache2, as Docker, in a VM, or just rent one and sleep easy.